# Did Barb and Adam own the hardware shop?

Tags: plot-explanation, beetlejuice

At the beginning of *Beetlejuice*, Barbara and Adam Maitland stop to get something from the local hardware shop- named Maitland Hardware. For a small town it seems an unlikely coincidence- did the shop belong to them, at least when they were alive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Yes

Firstly, although this did not make it into the movie the script includes a scene where Adam indicates that they are taking a vacation by adding a sign to the model of his store in his model town.

> ```
>    To see the real Winter River, laid out exactly as the
>    model, at the foot of the hill.  Adam breathes deeply
>    and looks very pleased at the glorious town below him.
>
>
>    ON HIS HUGE HAND AGAIN
>
>    as it reaches into model and tweezes a tiny sign into
>    the tiny window of Maitland's Hardware Store on main
>    street.  It reads:
>
>                ADAM AND BARBARA MAITLAND
>                           ARE
>                       ON VACATION!
>                          HOORAY!
> ```

Secondly, and perhaps more obviously, when Adam visits the store he **unlocks the door** clearly indicating that the store is, in fact, theirs.

> ```
>   Adam sprints up the steps of **his** lovely hardware store.
>    OLD BILL, a slightly-addled ancient barber, is napping
>    in a chair in front of his shop, next door to Adam's.
>    Adam fumbles with the lock, not interested in conversation.
> ```